# How can i capture microphone stream and change with ffmpeg?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyaudio

I am using ffmpeg for chancing wav file with below code on python;

```
song = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", sys.argv[1], "-af", "asetrate=22050,aresample=44100,atempo=2", "-f", "wav", "pipe:1"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But i want to send microphone stream to this subprocess. How can i change sys.argv[1] to microphone stream data?

I am using pyaudoio library for capturing sound in python.

Comment: You are already capturing microphone audio via pyaudio?

Comment: Yes i am. İ v got stream. How can i send stream to this terminal code and get changed version to directly speakers.

Comment: What format is the output from pyaudio? File or pipe?

Comment: İ m using thic code for pyauido mic stream p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt32,channel=2,rate=44000,output=True,stream_callback=callback)

Comment: `ffmpeg` can accept a file, or a pipe, or can possibly access the microphone directly.